# Ключи массива в value ChoiceType (Symfony 3)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3

Есть массив и менять его нельзя (array_flip() не подойдет):

```
$clients = [
    '1' => '123'
    '2' => '123'
    '3' => '456'
];
```

И есть простая форма:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('client_id', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => [
            'Add' => 'add',
            'Group' => $clients,
        ],
    ])
->getForm();
```

Которая даёт следующий результат:

```
<select>
    <option value="add">Add</option>
    <optgroup label="Group">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Как сделать, чтобы в value остались ключи, а в опшионах значения? Должно получиться так:

```
<select>
    <option value="add">Add</option>
    <optgroup label="Group">
        <option value="1">123</option>
        <option value="2">123</option>
        <option value="3">456</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Я не вижу разницы.

Comment: @u_mulder спасибо, исправил.